# How to find a 'str' in a 2-D array and return element in next column?

Tags: python, numpy

I've successfully combined two lists (A, B) using numpy.array and assigned it to a new variable. The first list contained strings (A) and the second contained integers (B). When I print the new variable (C) I get:

```
    [[Str, Str]
     [Int, Int]]
```

I'm now trying to find the corresponding integer if the str == 'XYZ'. How do I use the index function to find the int in the row next to 'XYZ'?

My initial thought was to assign the new list to a variabe i.e. D:

```
  D = C[A == 'XYZ',]
```

However, I only get True, False, etc.

Sorry, I know this is quite basic.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

`import numpy as np 
my_matrix = np.array([['ABC','XYZ'],[1,99]]) 
print(my_matrix)
my_index = my_matrix[0]=='XYZ' 
print(my_matrix[1][my_index])`

Comment: Thank you Mathew - that helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
  import numpy as np 
  A = ['ABC', 'XYZ']
  B = [1, 99]
  C = B[A == 'ABC']
  D = B[A != 'ABC']
  print(C)
  print(B)
```